# Primal of Dual of LP problem

Tags: linear-programming, duality-theorems, operations-research

Given that the following relation holds:
$$\begin{align*} &\textbf{Primal problem} \\ &\max Z = c^Tx \\ &s.t. \\ &Ax \leq b \\ & x \geq 0\end{align*}$$
$\Longrightarrow$
$$\begin{align*} &\textbf{Dual problem} \\ &\min W = b^Ty \\ &s.t. \\ &A^Ty \geq c \\ & y \geq 0\end{align*}$$
Derive the primal problem corresponding to the dual problem below, using only the relation given above.
$$\begin{align*} &\min W = b^Ty \\ &s.t. \\ &A^Ty \geq c \\ &y \text{ unrestricted}\end{align*}$$

I tried the following: Define $y^+ \geq 0$ and $y^-\geq 0$ such that $y = y^+ - y^-$ Then we have 
$$\begin{align*} &\min W = b^T(y^+ - y^-) = b^Ty^+ - b^T y^-  \\ &s.t. \\ &A^T (y^+ - y^- ) = A^Ty^+ - A^Ty^-\geq c \\ &y^+ \geq 0, y^-\geq 0\end{align*}$$
Then we make it into a maximisation problem:
$$\begin{align*} &\max W' = b^T(y^- - y^+)  \\ &s.t. \\ &A^T(y^- - y^+)\leq c \\ &y^+ \geq 0, y^-\geq 0\end{align*}$$
Then define $u:= y^- - y^+$, so that we have
$$\begin{align*} &\max W' = b^Tu  \\ &s.t. \\ &A^Tu\leq c \\ &u \text{ unrestricted}\end{align*}$$
And then I am stuck, any hints on how to continue?

Answer (score 0):

The question is asking how to convert the dual back into the primal.  After the substitution of $y^+ - y^-$ for $y$, you have
$$\begin{align*} 
\min  W &= b^Ty^+ - b^T y^- & \\
{\rm s.t.}  \hspace{1in} \\ 
A^Ty^+ - A^Ty^- & \geq c \\ 
y^+ & \geq 0 \\ 
 y^- &\geq 0
\end{align*}
$$

Moving back to the primal, you have one variable for each of the structural constraints, and separate constraints for each of the variables
$$ \begin{align*} 
\max Z & = c x \\
{\rm s.t.}  \hspace{1in} \\ 
A x & \le b \\
-A x & \le -b \\
x & \ge 0
\end{align*}
$$

Combining the two sets of structural constraints and the problem becomes
$$ \begin{align*} 
\max Z & = c x \\
{\rm s.t.}  \hspace{1in} \\ 
A x & = b \\
x & \ge 0
\end{align*}
$$